Pixel 7 Pro is not recognized by Windows 10 via USB
When I connect my Pixel 7 Pro with my laptop via USB it gets recharged but there is no data connection which I need to transfer data.
I have spent more than two days trying to resolve this problem but nothing has worked so far:

on other PCs (running Win 10 or Ubuntu) with the same USB wire it only gets recharged --> it's not the PC
other Android phone with the same USB wire: the phone gets recharged AND there is a data connection --> it's not the USB wire
I've tried installing USB drivers with Android Studio -> didn't changed the situation
I've tried to use the Windows device manager to find the Pixel phone -> it did not show up

I'm sure that I already had a successful connection with the very setup as I can see an older dump of photographs from my phone on that laptop.
I have one suspicion though. I recently have added a work profile to the phone and I've somewhere read that this could prevent establishing a data connection via USB to the phone due to enforcing some company policies.
Unfortunately, I have no clue where to start to repair this. I have now removed this work profile from the Pixel but this did not fix the problem.
Does anyone have an idea how to repair this connection?
Some of the other threads that I have found when searching for the problem:
[1] https://xdaforums.com/t/cant-connect-pixel-7-pro-to-pc-windows-11-solved.4574469/
[2] https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-see-my-Android-phone-in-My-Computer-after-connecting-it-to-my-PC-with-a-USB-cable
[3] https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-connect-pixel-7-to-windows-11/04b2f804-84f4-43c0-ba76-894c6d6d611d

The device has to be unlocked (lock screen pin/password/pattern have to be entered) and when you connect it via USB to a PC you should get a notification message that leads you to the USB settings where you can switch to data mode.

Also on the default USB connection, is it set to data transfer or something equivalent (since IDK your device settings)

ADB & fastboot drivers updated to the latest?

"I've tried installing USB drivers with Android Studio" I'm not sure how it works now, but if it was downloaded using SDK Manager, then AFAIR it's only downloading the drivers to the SDK folder, which should be manually installed from Device Manager.

@Robert yes, I was expecting this notification so I unlocked the phone after connecting it to the laptop but there was no notification except for: "I'm doing adaptive recharging".

@beeshyams unsure where I could set the default USB connection. My Pixel only recognize that it get power via the USB connection and recharges. There are no options to change the connection type. Can you point me to a source where and how I can check whether the ADB and fastboot drivers are up-to-date?

@AndrewT. I've also manually installed the downloaded drivers via a right-click on the *.inf-file in the drivers folder. Didn't change the situation.

What "other Android phone" have you tested? Phones can have USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 connectors and may be your USB cable works find with USB 2.0 (old phone) but fails in USB 3 mode? USB 3 introduces special wires in USB cables that have t be present for USB 3 mode.

@Robert it was a huawei P20 light. And while you have brought up an interesting fact, I'm pretty sure that I have used the same USB cable as before. So I'm very confident that data transfer has worked with the same setup in the past that doesn't work today. As I mentioned, my suspicion is that the work profile I've recently installed on the Pixel caused this trouble.


Enable developer options by tapping 7 times or more build number in about phone/device of your settings. Developer options are enabled. In those options check under default USB Configuration//2, Latest platform tools that have both adb and fastboot can be downloaded from here


Also install Pixel USB Drivers and if that doesn't help try Universal ADB drivers or from here

set default USB configuration to file transfer/ Android Auto

Huawei P20 lite has an USB 2.0 (Type-C) port, thus a partially defect USB 3 cable would a reasonable cause.

Thanks, @beeshyams. That looks like valueable input that I need to check out.

@Robert I have to admit that my USB cable is orignally from that Huawei phone. IIRC the Pixel phone didn't had one. So this should be a USB 2.0 Type-C cable from the Huawei phone, right? Does your argument also apply to that constellation? Should I get a brand new cable though it allows data transfer between Huawei phone and PC?

The Pixel phone normally come with USB-C-to-C cable. Normally an USB 3 phone connected with an USB 2.0 cable should make use of the USB wires and establish an USB 2 connection. May be the cable is wrongly detected as USB 3 cable and the phone tries only to use the USB 3 wires which fails. Therefore yes, my recommendation would be to by a new cable, I assume you need an USB3-C-to-A cable.

Finally, for me helped to intensively clean the USB socket on the phone. Turned out, much grime and filth has been stuck in that to a way it prohibited to connect correctly via USB.
